# Hosting a WCF service in Mono console application on Mac Os X

Tags: wcf, mono

When I try to host a WCF service, that works perfectly in Windows, in a mono console application I get the following error (*):

> An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.

I don't get at all why this is happening or where I need to look to fix this. Anyone who has experienced this or can point me in the right direction?

I am using Mono 2.10.8 on a Mac running Os X 10.6.8.

*Stacktrace:

```
 at System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2[System.Type,System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior].InsertItem (Int32 index, IOperationBehavior item) [0x0003a] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.ObjectModel/KeyedCollection.cs:168 
  at System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection`1[System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior].InsertItem (Int32 index, IOperationBehavior kind) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.Collections.Generic/KeyedByTypeCollection.cs:70 
  at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior].Add (IOperationBehavior item) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.ObjectModel/Collection.cs:74 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetOrCreateOperation (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd, System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi, System.Reflection.MethodInfo serviceMethod, System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute oca, System.Type asyncReturnType, Boolean isCallback, System.Type givenServiceType) [0x00511] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:350 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.FillOperationsForInterface (System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription cd, System.Type exactContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, Boolean isCallback) [0x00131] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:240 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContractInternal (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, System.Type serviceTypeForCallback) [0x001ed] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:190 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType, System.Type serviceTypeForCallback) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:136 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type givenContractType, System.Type givenServiceType) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:131 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescriptionGenerator.GetContract (System.Type contractType) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescriptionGenerator.cs:101 
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract (System.Type contractType) [0x00017] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Description/ContractDescription.cs:66 
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint (System.Type implementedContract, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.Uri address, System.Uri listenUri) [0x00022] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHost.cs:96 
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint (System.Type implementedContract, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.Uri address) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceHost.cs:85 
  at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0002b] in /Users/steven/Software/ABC Cloud/NooSphere/Mono.Host/Main.cs:16
```

Comment: I have been able to get a subset of the code running but due to the complexity of the code base I don't really know the precise cause of this very generic error. It seems that there are number of issues that are causing this including (i) incomplete support for WCF service discovery, (ii) servicecontract inheritance weirdness and (iii) azure libraries that are not supported. I am investigating this and will report any solutions I find.

Comment: I've filed https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6187 which seems similar to your problem. Do you have behaviors (like WebGet) on inherited operations?

Comment: Yes, I did. I fixed it in the end by moving all operations into one service contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Mono and has been fixed in [mono-2.10.9](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10.9) (Mac only updated) and [Mono for Android 4.2.7](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_4/mono_for_android_4.2.7)